# Model without endogeneity correction has lower AIC than one with correction

Tags: model-selection, aic, bic, endogeneity

I have two models, one with endogeneity correction (includes correction terms obtained using Heckman) and one without. The correction terms are significant in the second stage model, yet the AIC/BIC values of the model without the endogeneity correction is lower.

Significant correction terms suggest presence of endogeneity and hence the need to correct for the same. However, the AIC/BIC values suggest that correction is not required.

The model with the correction term makes more sense to me, but I would like to hear from the community about this anomaly and how do I justify using the model with the correction terms despite a higher AIC.